# Distribution of photons given an EM radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Given some EM radiation in vacuum, how can we calculate the probabilities or distribution of photons of different wavelengths? How might the results of the calculation change if the entire radiation's amplitude or occupied volume were to scaled by some constant factor?

Comment: It depends  on how that wave has emerged, the source.  EM radiation moves with velocity c, is not static. If in a cavity look here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Comment: @anna Can we use some sort of Fourier transform to derive the distribution for 'moving' EM radiation? If we have a very weak instance of EM radiation of frequency nu, so weak (due to small amplitude and/or short length along the direction of its Poynting vector) that its total energy is smaller than that of a photon of frequency nu, does that mean it won't actually be able to excite anything along its path that requires at least one photon of frequency nu?

Comment: the EM radiation is built up by photons. so A classical EM of frequency nu has zillions of photons of frequency nu. see https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Comment: @anna Even if an antenna were so small and its emission time so short that the entire energy emitted at frequency nu is less than h*nu, thus making zero the probability of having even a single higher-energy photon? Or, I suppose, the energy of emission in such cases inherently has large enough uncertainty to accommodate non-zero probability of higher-energy photons?

Comment: if you are not living in an alternate universe you should know that the smallest antenna will be an atom, and the atom can, if in an excited state emit a photon by transitioning to a lower energy level. At the framework of atoms there exist only photons of frequency conncted with their energy E=hnu.